# How to get length of array field present in PostgreSQL using Python Django Models

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This is my Django model:

```
class UserVpaUpiId(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    vpa_upi_id = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=False)
```

I want to delete an entry with a particular user_id, which I am able to do successfully using:

```
UserVpaUpiId.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).delete()
```

But, before that, I want to display the number of UPIs, which are stored in vpa_upi_id in the format:

```
["acbd.pq@icici", "9987654431@apl", "9876543210@apl"]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
vpa_upa_ids = UserVpaUpiId.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).values('vpa_upi_id')[0]['vpa_upi_id']
arr = vpa_upa_ids[1:-1].split(",")
length = len(arr)
```

Since you already have to user_id to delete the record you can grab the matching record(s), convert the result into a string and perform some string manipulations to turn it into an array where you can then grab the length.